# convert inner join query to subquery

Tags: sql, join, plsql, subquery, inner-join

I have 3 tables where I am trying to find answer combining them and try getting these columns

```
select student_name,course_title,last_name
from students
inner join student_enrollment
on students.student_no = student_enrollment.student_no
inner join courses
on courses.course_no = student_enrollment.course_no
inner join teach
on courses.course_no = teach.course_no
order by student_name
```

I want to convert my inner join query into a subquery , how can I achieve the same result? I have tried some but its not running

my attempted solution

```
  select (select student_name from students where students.student_no = student_enrollment.student_no) as student_name,
    (select last_name from teach where teach.course_no  = student_enrollment.course_no) as professor_name,
    (select course_title from courses where courses.course_no =  teach.course_no ) as course_title
    from student_enrollment
```

Comment: You may not be able to.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: but why I have mentioned the query with joins should be able to give enough insights on what to convert and how? if not i'll see what I can provide

Comment: Firstly why would you want to do that?  The first query is easier to read and I can not see any obvious performance reasons for the change...... Secondly you say it is not running... Is it giving you an error? if so what? or just the wrong results? if so as Gordon Linoff has pointed out we need what you expect vs what you are getting.

Comment: @ShaunPeterson I agree, second query is giving errors , I can paste them , just to be able to learn sql in a more deep way I wanted to see if i can write it in a sub query or not . I am not trying to do things hard way I am just trying to learn them in a hard way.

Comment: @ShaunPeterson the query I wrote is wrong. its not correct . I wanted a correct implementation of it.

Comment: @Belayer sorry I am stuck in somethinh, give e few hours I will provide the same. You shall have it in few hours

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what error you are getting but I believe your issue could be comming from the fact that in your third subquery you are trying to link to a table in your second subquery.

Each subquery does not know about the other, only about the tables in the main query.....

so where you have

```
courses.course_no =  teach.course_no
```

you can replace it with

```
courses.course_no = student_enrollment.course_no
```

Then I think you should work....

Have a look at the dbfiddle I have created below for an example that is similar

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=31aa8d0ab9e139d1eae2d50e703caff5